# Error with maven release process after upgrade to cloud parent

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, gitlab-ci, maven-release-plugin

My team started use spring cloud projects long time ago and we have a large number of microservices with working CI configuration. But after upgrading to the cloud parent our builds started to fail.

To configure our microservices we have an internal parent with some default configurations, dependencies and plugins. This parent was using the `spring-boot-starter-parent`:

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
```

And for `spring-cloud` we had the spring-cloud BOM dependency defined:

```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

We decided to use the `spring-cloud-starter-parent` to facilitate some dependency version management. Now we upgraded our own parent to use this parent:

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
```

Now our release process is getting some weird errors. Taking a single project for example (a simple one) we have this CI configured (for GitLab):

```yaml
image: maven:3-jdk-8
variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s settings.xml --batch-mode --errors --show-version"

cache:
  paths:
  - .m2/repository

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - git config --global user.name "Gitlab CI"
    - git config --global user.email "gitlab@email"
    - git checkout -B "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean versions:use-releases release:prepare -Dusername=$USERNAME -Dpassword=$USER_TOKEN
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -Darguments="-Dmaven.test.skip=true" clean release:perform -Dusername=$USERNAME -Dpassword=$USER_TOKEN
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS build-helper:remove-project-artifact
```

We use this configuration of `maven-release-plugin`:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
      <tagBase>${git-link}/tags</tagBase>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

After starting a CI pipeline, our build finished with this error:

```
    149809 [INFO] 144003 [INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:deploy (default-deploy) @ service-utilities-parent ---
    149820 [INFO] 144014 [ERROR] 
    149820 [INFO] Unsupported protocol: 'scp' for site deployment to distributionManagement.site.url=scp://static.springframework.org/var/www/domains/springframework.org/static/htdocs/spring-cloud/docs/spring-cloud-starter-parent/Greenwich.RELEASE.
    149821 [INFO] Currently supported protocols are: http, https, file.
    149821 [INFO]     Protocols may be added through wagon providers.
    149821 [INFO]     For more information, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/adding-deploy-protocol.html
```

I really have no clue of what is going on, since I have no `maven-site-plugin` defined and the `spring-cloud-starter-parent` should declare plugins only on `pluginsManagement` section.

I will be very happy if someone can explain me what I'm not seeing.

Thanks.

Comment: We don't recommend using spring-cloud-dependencies as a parent.

Comment: @spencergibb you say the `spring-cloud-starter-parent`? Because on Spring Cloud documentation it says:

`The release train contains a spring-cloud-dependencies as well as the spring-cloud-starter-parent. You can use the parent as you would the spring-boot-starter-parent (if you are using Maven).`

What I should do then?

I don't use the `spring-cloud-dependencies` as a parent, just the `spring-cloud-starter-parent` itself.

Comment: Import the bom as before

Comment: Thank you for the assist. I will import the BOM as before. I just don't get why spring documentation says that we can use the `spring-cloud-starter-parent`.

Comment: We should probably change the documentation to reflect better what we recommend